# How Can I use this field in a where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field that gets exported from a internal program that i cant change.  here is the field that gets exported to a SQL DB.
Here is the Field
title - year client [class tax type]

how can I use that in a where clause?  ive put brackets around that field and it wont work.

```
Select *
FROM [400_Tax]
where [title-year client [class tax type]] = 'Barnard'
```

Comment: `where "title-year client [class tax type]" = 'Barnard'` will be simplest way

Comment: The standard object delimiter in SQL is `"`. Various database products use their own delimieters like ` in MySQL and `[...]` in SQL Server

Comment: You can also use QUOTENAME to find out the "safe" name: select QUOTENAME('year client [class tax type]')